# Selection toolbar is gone

Tags: selection-tools

Selection toolbar is gone!
Hi, guys, I have downloaded the latest version of the Blender 2.8 (it is 22 June version). And now I can't see a selection toolbar which was earlier. Somebody can say how I can enable the  toolbar
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of how it was before? As rigth now I  do not fully understand what you mean by selection tool bar

Answer (score 2):

The select options are still available at the top of the 3d viewport, while the old version you had shows text buttons, these have now been replaced with icons.

You can find the options for the current tool in three places, in the 3D viewport header, the tool tab of the properties region and the active tool settings tab in the properties editor.

[image: tool option locations]

Note that we have four select tools, *Select*, *Select Box*, *Select Circle* and *Select Lasso*. The select tool has no options to show and the circle tool has less options. If you can't find the select tool options, it may be because you have the wrong select tool.

[image: various select tools]

Answer (score 0):

I have found, it's here on the right panel
[image]